# Creating two columns align left/right and vertical align bottom

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, fontsize, columns

I want a two column with varying sizes of text. I feel as though I'm close, but the font increase for the name section affects the vertical spacing for one of the lines in the left hand column. Any advice on how to make something like this?

```
\begin{tabu} to \textwidth { X[l,b]  X[r,b] }
    email@example.com \\ phone number \\ address \\ something else  & 
    \begingroup\fontsize{36pt}{12pt}\selectfont{Name Here}\endgroup \\
    \hline
\end{tabu}
```

[image]

Comment: A quick query: Does an answer, in order to be helpful to you, have to employ a `tabu` environment, or would a non-`tabu`-based solution be acceptable to you as well? Please advise.

Comment: Off-topic: (a) The instruction `\selectfont` does not take an argument. (b) The instruction `\fontsize{36pt}{12pt}` isn't quite correct: The second argument of `\fontsize` should be *at least as large* as the first argument. It just so happens to be the case that it's not fatal here, as the material affected by the font size change consists of a single line. You'd get a rather unpleasant surprise, though, if more than one line had to be typeset at `36pt`.

Comment: Tabu would be fine. And thanks for the info on fonts. I'm quite new to tex and haven't had time to read a lot of docs yet.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `tabular*`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern} % scalable fonts

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l l @{}}
\sffamily % for the left part
\begin{tabular}[b]{@{}l@{}}
email@example.com \\ 
phone number \\ 
address \\
something else  
\end{tabular}
&
\sffamily % for the right part
\fontsize{36}{45}\selectfont Name Here
\\
\hline
\end{tabular*}

\end{document}
```

This way you have a single object that can be placed wherever you please.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Here's a solution that employs a `tabular` environment, with alignment option `[b]` for the material on the left-hand side.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begingroup
\sffamily % optionally, switch to sans-serif
\noindent
\begin{tabular}[b]{@{}l}
  email@example.com \\ 
  phone number \\ 
  address \\
  something else  
\end{tabular} 
\hfill
\fontsize{36pt}{36pt}\selectfont 
name here
\hrule
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

Comment: Observe that the font-size change hasno effect on the line spacing *inside* the `tabular` environment.